# Rest web services(post) consumes json not working

Tags: java, json, web-services

So I am trying to create a simple webservice post that consumes json. But I am geting the error  `RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type`

My webservice:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("teste1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response teste1(String product) {

    String result = "Product created : " + product;
    System.out.println("resultado");
    System.out.println(result);
    return Response.ok() //200
            .entity("<erro> none </erro>")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With").build();

}
```

I also tried to do:

```
 @Consumes("application/json")
```

But I am getting the same error. **I can make it work if I do**:

```
  @Consumes("*/*")
```

But I can't understand why it doesn't work when I say it consumes json. To test the webservice I am using https://apitester.com/. With the folowing Post Data:

```
{
    "key" : "value",
    "array" : [
        { "key" : 1 },
        { "key" : 2, "dictionary": {
                "a": "Apple",
                "b": "Butterfly",
                "c": "Cat",
                "d": "Dog"
            } },
        { "key" : 3 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the

```
@Consumes("application/json")
```

specifies a content media type which webservice can handle.

But also you may need to explicitly specify an appropriate type in the `Content-Type` header for your request.

I am not familiar with the https://apitester.com but probably it does not send the *Content-Type* header by default

In such case your server can treat the request body as a plain text, for instance. That request would not be routed to your endpoint, because it is not designed for the plain text.

Setting the `@Consumes(*/*)` fixes that problem, because the wrong media type matches that pattern as well.

Could you please ensure that you sends the `Content-Type: application/json` with your POST request?